# How do I install Inventory Management Software?

Tags: install-from-source

I am relatively new to Ubuntu- about a year- and I have still yet to figure out how to install something that is not in the software center, nor have I figured out how to use SPM for files that are not already listed. I currently run 12.04

I am trying to test run some inventory management software

http://www.inventory-management.org/

and all of the basic "this is how you install things dummy" articles are not yielding any results.

It's web based somehow but I have to install something? I don't know, I'm just looking for a way to stop manually counting inventory on a spreadsheet every week at work. There is no .deb file that I can find to cram it in to the software center. I'm stuck and at the end of my tiny little thread of knowledge about this process.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the package, you need to have `php5`, `mysql`, and `php5-mysql`. You also need to have a webserver installed that can serve the pages in the package. Most people tend to use Apache, which can be installed with `apache2`. Don't forget that you will also need the PHP5 plugin for Apache, so Apache knows how to handle PHP files. You can install that with `libapache2-mod-php5`.

Basically:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server php5-mysql apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
```

After that, you will need to setup Apache with the configuration that you would like it to run, such as where it should serve files from. I believe Apache2 defaults to using `/var/www` these days. You will also have to setup the PHP5 and MySQL extensions in Apache2.

You will also need PHPMyAdmin installed, unless you want to import the `site.sql` file manually. You can install PHPMyAdmin with:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

If you'd rather not install PHPMyAdmin, you can always just import the `site.sql` file through MySQL on the command line. Taken straight from the manpages of MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab
```

There is an article [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) that covers installing the LAMP stack on Ubuntu.